# Google Sheets availability chart formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am putting an overtime sheet together that staff can show their availability for the Saturday on a table with name and date with a simple Y/N, I also have another table for the hours each person has accumulated.

Based on several staff members saying Y to their availability (we have two members of staff in) I would like two cells to display the name of staff that has the least number of hours to their name.

Comment: You only want to return the person with the least hours who is marked Yes? Or you want a list of everyone who marked Yes from least hours to most? Should be fairly simple to accomplish either with the =Query function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I want to return the two people with the least hours. So cell 1 should display the least hour (That marked Y)

Comment: and cell 2 should display the second least hours (That marked Y). Any example code would be apprecciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with examples of desired output

Answer (score 0):

- Column A is the name
- Column B is the hours they have worked
- Column C is the checkbox, 
  checked meaning they will work overtime.

The following formula will return the two willing to work overtime with the least hours.

```
=query(A:C,"select * where A is not null and C = TRUE order by B limit 2")
```